# I need to replace only the String values as None from the given List . List = ['Gopi',10,30,True,'Babu',10.21] In Python

Tags: python, list

the given list is : List = ['Gopi',10,30,True,'Babu',10.21].
Here I have to replace only the String values to None in  python.
Can someone help we with this.
expected o/p - List = ['None',10,30,True,'None',10.21]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has the [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function that lets you get the type of your variable.

Therefore you can loop on your array and check if the type is String before replacing it by None.

Comment: Yes thats correct i tried but i am not getting the desired output . the desired output should be lst = ['None',10,30,True,'None',10.21]. this is what i tried lst = ['Gopi',10,30,True,'Babu',10.21]
for i in range(0,len(lst)):    
        if(lst[i]==str):
            lst[i] = None

Comment: i can find the type but How to replace it ?

Comment: `type(lst[i])==str:` just try this

Comment: @bhavya parikh -I can find the string in the list but how do i replace the string with None

Comment: lst = ['Gopi',10,30,True,'Babu',10.21]
for i in range(0,len(lst)):    
        if(type(lst[i])==str):
            lst[i] = None           
            print(lst[i])                                                                     for this the O/p is None,None so the two string are replaced by none , but i want the o/p to be List = ['None',10,30,True,'None',10.21]

Comment: `>>> lst = ['Gopi',10,30,True,'Babu',10.21]
>>> for i in range(0,len(lst)):
...     if (type(lst[i]) == str):
...             lst[i] = "None"
...
>>>
>>> print(lst)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the whole list and check if each item is string with

```
isinstance(item, str)
```